# ¿Ejecutar Macro de excel con Python?

Tags: python, excel, vba

Estoy tratando de ejecutar una macro de excel desde python, para ello tengo el siguiente código:

```
import win32com.client as w3c

def ejecuntar_macro():
    xlApp_mrapp = w3c.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    pw_str = str('Plantilla123')
    mrapp = r'D:\Proyectos\Tablero estados\Tablero.xlsm'
    xlApp_mrapp.Visible = True
    xlApp_mrapp.DisplayAlerts = False 
    wb = xlApp_mrapp.Workbooks.Open(mrapp, False, False, None, pw_str)
    xlApp_mrapp.Application.Run("'" + mrapp + "'" + "!Módulo1.guardar_archivo")
    wb.Close(True)
    xlApp_mrapp.Quit()

ejecuntar_macro()
```

Pero lo anterior me esta generando el siguiente error:

> File ".\ejecucion.py", line 244, in ejecuntar_macro
> xlApp_mrapp.Application.Run("'" + mrapp + "'" + "!Módulo1.guardar_archivo")   File "<COMObject >", line 14,
> in Run   File
> "C:\Users\Ruben\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py",
> line 314, in *ApplyTypes*
> result = self.*oleobj*.InvokeTypes(*(dispid, LCID, wFlags, retType, argTypes) + args) pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567,
> 'Ocurrió una excepción.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146788248), None)

Me pueden ayudar por favor a resolver este problema.  Muchas gracias